# Rails Actionmailer Send email to all users EXCEPT

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Right now I have a really simple mailer:

```
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@example.com"

  def weekly(email)
    mail to: email, subject: "500 Points for liquid.radio!"
  end
end
```

What I really want to do is send an email to all Users.  The problem is that, a while back, there was a problem getting the email addresses from the facebook users, so as a temporary solution I generated a generic "xxxxxxx@facebook.com" email address for each user that wasn't able to get it from omni-auth.

So now what I would like to do is email all users EXCEPT for the ones with the "@facebook.com" email address.

Once that's setup I usually send the emails from the console like this:

```
ExampleMailer.weekly("example@gmail.com").deliver
```

I would imagine I'll have to find a different way to do that if I'm going to email all the users (except for the facebook ones.)

Comment: I think one way approaching this issue is to add an extra boolean attribute to user model, for example is_facebook_user -> true/false. Then you can get those users with the following query User.where(is_facebook_user: false). I think you could also use some kind of RegEx filter in the mailer but, I think by using is_facebook_user attribute is faster. There could be also some other approaches to this issues as well. I'm quite new with the ActionMailer, so this was an interesting question.

Comment: That's a good idea. Looks like you're the only one. :)